# How can I show that $\{ x = (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} : x_k = n \}$ is open

Tags: general-topology

How can I show for all $m$ and $n$ the openness of
the following set :

$\{ x =(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} : x_k = m \}$

Thanks in advance !

Comment: $m$ and $k$, you mean ? Moreover, you should precise which topology you are considering.

Comment: Which topology are you using here? I can guess, but it should be included in the question.

Comment: Presumably the topology is the product topology of the discrete topologies on each $\Bbb N$. Recall that projection maps are continuous.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$be a topological space equipped with
the product topology, where each component $\mathbb{N}$ is equipped
with discrete topology.

Let $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ be fixed. Define $A=\{x\in X\mid x(m)=n\}$.
Then $A$ is open.

Proof: Note that $A^{c}=\{x\in X\mid x(m)\neq n\}$. We go to show
that $A^{c}$ is closed. Let $(x,D,\leq)$ be a net in $A^{c}$. Here
$(D,\leq)$ is a directed system and $x:D\rightarrow A^{c}$. Suppose
that the net $(x,D,\leq)$ converges to $y\in X$. For each $\alpha\in D$,
$x_{\alpha}\in A^{c}\Rightarrow x_{\alpha}(m)\neq n$. Since $x_{\alpha}\rightarrow y$,
we have $x_{\alpha}(m)\rightarrow y(m)$. It follows that $y(m)\neq n$
because the topology on the $m$-th component $\mathbb{N}$ is discrete.
Therefore $y\in A^{c}$.

Comment: Overly complicated?

Answer (score 0):

Your set equals $\pi_k^{-1}[\{m\}]$, the inverse image of the open set $\{m\}$ of $\mathbb{N}$ under the projection onto the $k$-th coordinate, which is continuous, because the product topology is the smallest topology that makes all projections continuous. Hence it's open by the definition of continuity.